# Как последовательно менять текст в QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Хотелось бы чтобы когда человек нажимал на кнопку, то высвечивался текст "Donone!", а затем уже "Успешно!", но какие костыли бы я не применял, чтобы сначала высвечивался один текст, а затем уже он заменялся другим - всё безрезультатно. Питон будто нарочно обходит `self.ui.label_14.setText("Donone!")` выводя самый последний текст `self.ui.label_14.setText("Успешно!")`.

Что я делаю не так?

```
def button_clicked(self):  # блок команд, выполняющийся при нажатии кнопки
    print(1)
    self.ui.label_14.setText("Donone!")
    self.ui.label_14
    time.sleep(1)

    print(2)
    self.ui.label_14.setText("Успешно!")
    self.ui.label_14
```

Comment: Что вы делаю не так? Вы не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует вашу проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Питон не виноват (такое же поведение вы получите и в Qt на С++, и на любом другом языке) - виджеты обновляются/перерисовываются после завершения работы соответствующего метода который их изменяет, в данном случае `button_clicked`. Соответственно, когда метод завершается в метке остается последнее установленное значение. Ну и следовательно, чтобы увидеть изменение текста в метке нам надо где-то раздобыть два метода (либо иметь параллельное изменение в GUI из работающего метода другого потока, но это не наш случай).

Вот так должно сработать (метод [QTimer.singleShot](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96602/PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer.singleShot)):

```py
def button_clicked(self): 
    self.ui.label_14.setText("Done!")    

    # обновляем метку с текстом
    self.repaint() # без этого вызова тоже должно работать нормально

    # через одну секунду вызовем лямбду и обновим метку снова
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.ui.label_14.setText("Успешно!"))
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы знаете своё дело! Для тех, кто столкнётся с проблемой отсутствия QTimer в проекте, импортируйте "from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer". Мира вам!

Answer (score 0):

У pyqt5 есть класс QBasicTimer, думаю он может решить вашу проблему

Comment: Мм... каким образом если не секрет?

Comment: при клике ставите текст Donone запускаете таймер и при обработке этого таймера ставите текст Успешно

Answer (score 0):

Для вещей не связанных с таймером используйте [processEvents](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)